# Problema al traer datos de una base

Tags: php, mysql, html5, mysqli

estoy teniendo un problema.
Lo que quiero hacer y estoy intentando lograr es un menu
donde traiga como "link/s principal/es" las categorias ej:
"Placa de video"
Y que al dar click muestre las marcas de placa de video.
Ej:

No Click: Placa de Video

1er Click: MSI

2do click 1GB - 2GB - 4GB - 8GB

(a futuro quiero implementar esto del 2do click / 2do hover).

Aqui tengo el codigo con la consulta sql + php:

```
                <?php
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM categorias";
$consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM marcas";

$filas = mysqli_query($cnx, $consulta);
while( $columnas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($filas) ){
$filas2 = mysqli_query($cnx, $consulta2);
while( $columnas2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($filas2) ){

?>
    <li class="sub-miz">

        <a href="#">
            <?php echo $columnas['categoria']; ?></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#"><?php echo $columnas2['marca']; ?></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1yc1.png "primer ejemplo",

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oXRp.png "segundo ejemplo",

Esto es lo que quiero lograr:

[3] https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLFbt.png "intentando esto"

Quiero que cada categoria tenga nombre y dentro las marcas del tipo de categoria.

como dije arriba EJEMPLO:

```
Placa Video > MSI

Placa Madre > MSI

Procesadores > Intel

             > AMD
Fuentes > Sentey
```

Desde ya, gracias.

Jukxz

EDIT:

Base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE `marcas` (
`id_marca` int(50) NOT NULL,
`marca` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`categoria` varchar(50) NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `marcas` (`id_marca`, `marca`) VALUES
(1, 'AMD'),
(2, 'ASUS'),
(3, 'INTEL'),
(4, 'NVIDIA'),
(5, 'MSI'),
(6, 'LOGITECH'),
(7, 'ROG'),
(14, 'GENIUS'),
(15, 'SAMSUNG'),
(16, 'RAZER'),
(17, 'CORSAIR'),
(18, 'ROSEWILL'),
(19, 'EVGA'),
(20, 'GIGABYTE');
CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
`id_categoria` int(50) NOT NULL,
`categoria` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `categorias` (`id_categoria`, `categoria`) VALUES
(1,'Placas de Video');

ALTER TABLE `categorias`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_categoria`),
ADD UNIQUE KEY `id_categoria` (`id_categoria`),
ADD KEY `categoria` (`categoria`);

ALTER TABLE `marcas`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_marca`),
ADD UNIQUE KEY `id_marca` (`id_marca`);
ALTER TABLE `categorias`
MODIFY `id_categoria` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `marcas`
MODIFY `id_marca` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=21;
ALTER TABLE `marcas`
ADD CONSTRAINT `cat_key` FOREIGN KEY (`categoria`) REFERENCES `categorias`             
(`categoria`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: puedes mostrar los datos de las tablas para orientarme?

Comment: @KevinDelva acabo de actualizar el post con la base.

Comment: por favor mira [ask] y [tour]. Las preguntas deben incluir las imagenes en la misma pregunta y no links a ellas (no todos las pueden abrir)

Comment: Hola, @gbianchi segun vi al crear el post, la herramienta misma da varias formas de poner imgs, esta disponible esa forma de poner las imagenes. Mil disculpas, estoy con un internet muy bajo y fue la opcion mas rapida.